# Thread execution

Tags: servlets, webserver, websphere, java-threads

I have a web application that checks the user accounts from the database to determine their source. I want to make sure that the thread that goes to check the database runs first without any scheduling algorithm of WebSphere server.

More Clarification:
Even if I define the method at first it takes time to gather all information so I want to make sure that the thread completes getting all the information from the database and proceed to other threads in the server.

Comment: Could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [javax.servlet.ServletContexetListener.contextInitialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) ?

Note that the JavaDoc states "All ServletContextListeners are notified of context initialization before any filters or servlets in the web application are initialized."